# Show reports tab on Salesforce1 app for a PartnerCommunity User

Tags: salesforce1-app, partner-communities

I'm trying to add report tab to the Salesforce1 app navigation menu for a PartnerCommunity user. Does anyone know if it's possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here, not possible..

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cCVQAA2